# Add distinct count of a column to each row in PySpark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I need to add distinct count of a column to each row in PySpark dataframe.

Example:
If the original dataframe is this:

```
+----+----+
|col1|col2|
+----+----+
|abc |   1|
|xyz |   1|
|dgc |   2|
|ydh |   3|
|ujd |   1|
|ujx |   3|
+----+----+
```

Then I want something like this:

```
+----+----+----+
|col1|col2|col3|
+----+----+----+
|abc |   1|   3|
|xyz |   1|   3|
|dgc |   2|   3|
|ydh |   3|   3|
|ujd |   1|   3|
|ujx |   3|   3|
+----+----+----+
```

I tried `df.withColumn('total_count', f.countDistinct('col2'))` but it's giving error.

Comment: I'm getting this error message: ```AnalysisException: grouping expressions sequence is empty, and 'siteDomain' is not an aggregate function. Wrap '(count(DISTINCT `UserId`) AS `total_network_users`)' in windowing function(s) or wrap 'siteDomain' in first() (or first_value) if you don't care which value you get.;;```
 I'm getting error while using your way as well: ```TypeError: 'DataFrame' object does not support item assignment```

Comment: This happens because **countDistinct** is an aggregate function, so it demmands a grouping or an aggregation so it can works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can count distinct elements in the column and create new column with the value:

```
distincts = df.dropDuplicates(["col2"]).count()
df = df.withColumn("col3", f.lit(distincts))
```

Answer (score 2):

Cross join to the count distinct as below:

```
df2 = df.crossJoin(df.select(F.countDistinct('col2').alias('col3')))

df2.show()
+----+----+----+
|col1|col2|col3|
+----+----+----+
| abc|   1|   3|
| xyz|   1|   3|
| dgc|   2|   3|
| ydh|   3|   3|
| ujd|   1|   3|
| ujx|   3|   3|
+----+----+----+
```

Comment: I think instead of a crossJoin, using the count of the distinct element and then using `lit(count)` would be much faster.

Comment: @user238607 not sure, maybe it's similar due to the sheer simplicity of the operation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Window**, **collect_set** and **size**:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window

df = spark.createDataFrame([("abc", 1), ("xyz", 1), ("dgc", 2), ("ydh", 3), ("ujd", 1), ("ujx", 3)], ['col1', 'col2'])

window = Window.orderBy("col2").rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, Window.unboundedFollowing)

df.withColumn("col3", F.size(F.collect_set(F.col("col2")).over(window))).show()

+----+----+----+
|col1|col2|col3|
+----+----+----+
| abc|   1|   3|
| xyz|   1|   3|
| dgc|   2|   3|
| ydh|   3|   3|
| ujd|   1|   3|
| ujx|   3|   3|
+----+----+----+
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question. I want distinct count of `col2`, not unique length of `col1` string.

Comment: I see... I just fixed the answer. Is that it?